# How to find specific words in a text and count them using python?

Tags: python, dictionary, count

I want to check if certain words appear in an input text and if so, how many times.

Those are my inputs:

- List of words: `keywords = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "lemon"]`
- Text to scan: `text = "This apple is very tasty but the banana is not delicious at all."`

Now I want to count how many times a word from the keywords list appears in the input text.

So the output should look something like that for this example:

`I found 2 words.

This is what I got so far, but it's outputting 0 instead of 2 in that case.

```
text = "This apple is very tasty but the banana is not delicious at all."

keywords = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "lemon"]

def dictionary_score(text):
    wordcount=0
    for line in text:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.lower()
        words = line.split(" ")
        for word in words:
            if keywords in words:
                wordcount += 1
print(f"I found {wordcount} words")
```

Where is the problem with the correct counting?

Comment: use `collections.Counter`

Comment: solved, thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `text` is a string, and `for line in text` iterates on the characters of the string. Can be replaced by `for line in text.splitlines():`
2. should be `if word in keywords:` instead of `if keywords in words:`

   ````
   text = "This apple is very tasty but the banana is not delicious at all."
   keywords = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "lemon"]

   def dictionary_score(text):
       wordcount=0
       for line in text.splitlines():
           print(line)
           line = line.strip()
           line = line.lower()
           words = line.split(" ")
           for word in words:
               if word in keywords:
                   wordcount += 1
       print(f"I found {wordcount} words") 

   dictionary_score(text)```
   ````

Output: `I found 2 words`

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with `if keywords in words:`. It checks whether the entirety of the `keywords` list is within your `words` list.

You probably wanted to check whether each `word` is in the `keywords` list:

```
if word in keywords:
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several errors:

```
text = "This apple is very tasty but the banana is not delicious at all."
keywords = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "lemon"]

def dictionary_score(text):
    wordcount=0
    for line in text: #Iterate over each string character
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.lower()
        words = line.split(" ") #Here the list will be empty, because you are operating on a character.
        for word in words: #You are iterating over a empty list
            if keywords in words: #Checking if the list keywords is in words(that is empty)
                wordcount += 1
print(f"I found {wordcount} words")
```

- `for line in text:` is iterating over each character of the string, after taking the char you string, lower and split it.
- `if keywords in words:` here you are checking that the keywords list is in words list, that is empty because the previous explanation.

Here the fixed code:

```
text = "This apple is very tasty but the banana is not delicious at all."
keywords = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "lemon"]

def dictionary_score(text):
    wordcount = 0
    words = text.strip().lower().split(" ") #split the string, after stripping and lowering it
    for word in words: # Iterate over the words
        if word in keywords: # If the word is in the keywords list increment the counter
            wordcount += 1
    print(f"I found {wordcount} words") 

dictionary_score(text)
```

output: `I found 2 words`

Answer (score 0):

Use Counter in collections

```
from collections import Counter
text = "This apple is very tasty but the banana is not delicious at all."
dict_words = Counter(text.split(" "))
dict_word.get("apple", 0 ) #Get the word count for apple
```